# How can I determine which furnace draft inducer is a compatible replacement?

Tags: furnace, electric-motor

I'm replacing my draft inducer / booster and I'm not sure how to find a suitable upgrade and from what I have found this seems to be the exact part [FASCO A985 (7085-1124, 330701`-701FA)](https://www.cshincorporated.com/a985-fasco-replacement-furnace-blower-7058-1124-330701-701fa/).

Is this something that can be upgraded or do I need to stick with an identical part? What are the most important numbers match?

*sticker on extrusion around rotating piece*

```
FASCO         70581124      05-10x
J238-150 Cust P/N ICP330701-701FA
115V             60Hz
2.4FLA          E64080
3.3LRA  T.P.L.    B  E48562
T.P.  3000 RPM    LR20432
```

*sticker on larger body*

```
+--------+
|._  .  ,| XJ1124-134
| = _,  .| 70581124J
| ,.=  _.|   0431 1
+--------+
   0431
```

** EDIT **

Furnace Info per @FreeMan's suggestion

[image]

** EDIT **

I purchased a [replacement draft inducer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00FAU1O5A) and will post back how the replacement goes.

Comment: Others may find it helpful if you include the make/model of the existing furnace. There may be differences.

Comment: @FreeMan I posted an image from the furnace body but reading over it I'm not sure how helpful that info is. If I need to post different info please let me know thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by upgrading? Are you looking to increase heat output, efficiency, longevity, reduce noise, something else?

Comment: What would you call an "upgrade"? The inducer is meant to ensure adequate combustion air for a given burner size and complete discharge of exhaust air to outside.  Have you determined that it is failing to do that? If it is performing its function, what would you be aiming for in an upgrade?

Comment: The bearings are starting to go on this one, it otherwise works great. I see now that "upgrade" may be misleading and it would have been better to say "replacement". I'm having a hard time finding an exact match locally so I'm more-so curious what I can replace this one with ie. what are the numbers I need to match - is it the `7058-1124` or `330701-701FA` etc etc

Answer (score 1):

In my experience (with draft inducers and many other appliance parts), searching the original part number tends to lead to plenty of aftermarket options. They usually refer to part numbers that they're intended to replace out of necessity--otherwise no one would find them.

Draft inducers in particular, while probably cross-compatible with multiple furnace models, tend to be somewhat proprietary. You'd want a nearly identical replacement to ensure proper mounting, sensor compatibility, power draw, etc. It's best not to guess or rely solely on numeric specifications.

So, find a replacement of any brand you consider trustworthy that correlates with your original part number *or* furnace model. I've also found it difficult to find local replacements, so I either contact local wholesale distributors or just buy online. The big river has pretty much everything.

Comment: I tend to go with places that specialize in appliance repair parts. They tend to have exploded drawing, part numbers, replacement part number, and sometimes even videos on how to do the replacement. Other places can leave you up the river without a UL-listed paddle.